# Unexpected results while reading conf file from resource folder

Tags: java

I have this following java code which reads `config.properties` from resource folder.

```
 import java.io.InputStream;
 import java.util.Properties;

    public class TestProperties {

         static ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
         static InputStream input = classloader.getResourceAsStream("config.properties");

        public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
            while (true) {
                new TestProperties().readPropertiesFile();
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            }
        }

        private void readPropertiesFile() {
            Properties properties = new Properties();

            try {
                properties.load(input);
                int threads = Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("num_of_workers"));
                System.out.println("num_of_workers: " + threads);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("hey something went wrong: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

Results:

- num_of_workers: 2
- hey something went wrong: null
- hey something went wrong: null
- hey something went wrong: null

**It gives me result (`num_of_workers: 2`) for first itration but after that it gives null**.

But when I change

- `static ClassLoader classloader` to `ClassLoader classloader`
- `static InputStream input` to `InputStream input`

I get expected result:

- num_of_workers: 2
- num_of_workers: 2
- num_of_workers: 2
- num_of_workers: 2

Can you please explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Because input stream can be used only once, 
in case of static it is initialized only once and you consumed in first iteration but in case of non static it is always created new when a new instance is created every time.

Comment: consumed? does it work like a queue(i.e after use it gets deleted)

Comment: not queue man you used it in first iteration. Once you used it you cannot simply use it again. you need to reset it if you want to read it again

Comment: do you mean we can use Input stream only one time

Comment: simply we can use input stream only once but if you are using mark and reset method you can reuse it but mark method is not supported by All input stream